# Message Formatting for Integration of Telegram Bot in DialogFlow (API.AI)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

After successful integration of DialogFlow agent with Telegram Bot.
I discovered that **double stars** `**` was not formatting the text into bold.

I know that setting up parse_mode to Markdown in sendMessage API can properly parse the texts but, DialogFlow integration doesn't show options as such while integrating.

Answer (score 5):

For formatting a Telegram message, you need to send an extra parameter `parse_mode` which you can set to `html` and format the text the way you want, like **bold**, *italic*, <strike>strikethrough</strike> etc.

For formatting a static Telegram message from Dialogflow you need to set the custom payload for Telegram in **response** as shown in the picture below

[image: Static Dialogflow formatted response for Telegram]

For formatting a message from webhook, you need to attach the custom payload for Telegram in response body which finally looks like this.

```
{
"fulfillmentText": "",
"fulfillmentMessages": [{
    "text": {
        "text": [""]
    }
}],
"payload": {
    "telegram": {
        "text": "<b>hello formatted custom telegram text</b>",
        "parse_mode": "html"
    }
},
"outputContexts": []
```

}

You can find more about Dialogflow rich messages here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-rich-messages.

Though it's really late response, I hope it helps those who need it now.